# How can I change ol.source.OSM tile url based on level (z value)

Tags: openlayers-3

We supply tiles for levels 0-9. So when the user goes to a zoom level 10 or higher I want the URL to change back to the default values of Open Street Map.

I've tried this and it almost works. When level 10 or higher is selected I change the URL using the ol.source.OSM.setURLs() function. But in some cases - not all - the image is still set to our local URL. I'm assuming this is some kind of caching issue but not sure.

```
$scope.tilesource = new ol.source.OSM({
    url : '/'+$scope.tileRoot+'/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    wrapX : false
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source : $scope.tilesource
});

$scope.tilesource.on('tileloadstart', function(arg) {
    //console.log(arg.tile.src_);
    if ($scope.tileLevelsSupported.search(arg.tile.tileCoord[0]) == -1) {
        $scope.tilesource.setUrls(["https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", "https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", "https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"]);
    } else {
        $scope.tilesource.setUrl('/'+$scope.tileRoot+'/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
    }
});
```

I've tried several methods on OSM and Tile but have had no luck. On those instances when the Tile URL is wrong I get the File Not Found 404 error (expected), but then it corrects itself and the tile gets loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the URL, you could use two different layers with the `minResolution` and `maxResolution` options:

```
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source : $scope.tilesource,
    minResolution: 200,
    maxResolution: 10000000
});

var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    minResolution: 0,
    maxResolution: 200
});
```

When you zoom in from level 9 to 10, the raster layer will become invisible and the osm layer will appear.

Comment: And if you need to treat these 2 layers as only one, for example to control their visibility in a layer tree, you could add them in a `ol.layer.Group` and manage the group only.